# How do I prevent GoogleFinance from rounding stock prices?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am trying to make a stock portfolio in Google Sheets to track my stonks. However, I have some penny stocks that are less than 1 penny, and GoogleFinance rounds them down to 0, making it impossible to calculate % of the portfolio. The code I use is:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(B2)
```

and neither adding the `ROUND` function or changing how numbers are displayed in excel are working. Is there a fix or do I have to scrape from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2); "#.00")*1
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, it still rounds 0.0018 to 0.00, even when I change it to #.0000. However, I did just change it so it scrapes off the Google Finance Website. Thank you for your quick response. -Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this reddit thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pennystocks/comments/lc4fg1/using_importxml_to_input_live_penny_stock_quotes/

You have to use importxml function and make sure the google sheets cell is set to show at least 4 decimal places.

Comment: Does `IMPORTXML` auto-update itself often to get and show the current value?